# attribute error using linked lists in python

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list

Am new to python and am trying my hand on simulating how linked list works. I have the following code:

```
def mystery(x):
  a , b = x , x.next.next
  while b.next != None:
    a.next.next = b.next
    b.next = a.next
    a.next = b
    a = b
    b = b.next.next
```

but when ever I give it the list 'x' which is x = ['1','2','3','4', '5'], I get the following error:

```
  File "D:\workspace33\Quizes\src\tests.py", line 3, in mystery
a , b = x , x.next.next
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'next'
```

I was trying to simulate/visulaize the program on [Online Python Tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display) 
but I kept getting the same error. Can anyone let me know what am doing wrong or help me understand the process.

Comment: Why do you think lists have a `next` attribute? (they don't)

Comment: Python lists, such as your `x = ['1','2','3','4', '5']`, are not linked lists.

Comment: @TimCastelijns- Thanks, how would I go about using the program?

Comment: @BoJaNgLeS: I suggest you Google "Python linked list" for lots of information on implementing linked lists in Python. (It's not a native feature of the language; you have to roll your own.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linked lists can be implemented with python lists if `.next` is replaced by `[1]`.  Here is an example with your program so transformed.

```
def mystery(x):
  a , b = x, x[1][1]
  while b[1] != None:
    a[1][1] = b[1]
    b[1] = a[1]
    a[1] = b
    a = b
    b = b[1][1]
  return a, b

ll = [0, [1, [2, [3, None]]]]
print(mystery(ll))
# ([2, [1, [3, None]]], [3, None])
```

If you want, you can step through this program in Idle by turning on the debugger (in the Shell window) before running it from an editor window.  When reaching the print line, click [over] instead of  [step] (or disable the print).

Comment: @TerryJanReedy- does this program do the exact same thing as the original one?

Comment: In terms of how links are accessed and manipulated, yes.  I did the indicated Find/Replace-all in the mystery function.  If you write an LL class and create an equivalent input, you should get an equivalent output.